# Is a cable between two OTG devices 5 wires?

Tags: usb

Is a cable between two OTG devices 5 wires?

I've heard different things..

I heard that USB OTG involves a 5th pin. shorting that ID 5th pin of micro-USB plug to GND, instructs it to act as host and provide 5V (which  btw costs battery on that device). I heard that the pin is shorted, or is not shorted, but either way, there's no 5th wire in the cable.

But I also read https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1047762.aspx  that "If you connect 2 OTG devices, the cable needed is "special" (5th signal)."   (So, based on that, it sounds like there is a 5th wire).

I'm thinking mainly about USB 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a cable between two OTG devices 5 wires?

No, a USB 2.x cable has only four conductors/wires plus (optional) shielding.

> I heard that USB OTG involves a 5th pin. shorting that ID 5th pin of micro-USB plug to GND, instructs it to act as host and provide 5V (which btw costs battery on that device). I heard that the pin is shorted, or is not shorted, but either way, there's no 5th wire in the cable.

That's essentially accurate, although the "*shorted, or is not shorted*" phrase is ambiguous since there's nothing specifically mentioned as the connection.  Since you previously mention a short to ground, the reader could/should infer that you are again referring to shorts to ground.

> But I also read https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1047762.aspx that "If you connect 2 OTG devices, the cable needed is "special" (5th signal)." (So, based on that, it sounds like there is a 5th wire).

That is poorly worded, and prompted an incorrect inference.
The fifth pin, typically labeled with the `ID` signal, is always an input.
The system with the OTG port has to use this `ID` input to determine if this USB connection will be as a USB host, or if this USB connection will be a USB device (aka gadget).

How (or from where) is this `ID` input originate?

Consider the possible cable configurations available:

- a male Type A connector on one end, and a male micro USB connector on the other end.
  The former plug is solely intended for a USB host port, since only a USB host would have a female Type A connector.
  So the other end of the cable is intended to plug into a USB gadget, since USB does not have peer-to-peer or host-to-host connections, and only gadgets connect to the host.
  Since the Type A connector only has four pins, there is no need for a 5th wire because there is no additional signal that originates from the host to send to the gadget.
  The cable is constructed so that the `ID` level/signal is left floating at the micro USB connector by connecting nothing to the `ID` pin.

  (A power-only cable with just 2 wires would also have the `ID` pin disconnected.)

  (Presumably the OTG port has a pull-up so that an unconnected `ID` input would be sensed as a logic high.  If the input is tied to ground, then a logic low would be read.)
- a female Type A connector on one end, and a male micro USB connector on the other end.
  The former socket is solely intended for a USB gadget to plug in, since only a USB gadget would have a male Type A connector.
  So the other end of the cable is intended to plug into a USB host, since USB does not have peer-to-peer or gadget-to-gadget connections, and a gadget must connect to a host.
  Since the Type A connector only has four pins, there is no need for a 5th wire because there is no additional signal that originates from the gadget to send to the other end of the cable.
  The cable is constructed so that the `ID` level/signal is a logic low at the micro USB connector by connecting the `ID` pin to the `GND` pin.
- male micro USB connectors on both ends of the cable.
  Such a cable would have to have one end designated as the A or host end, and the other end designated as the B or gadget end.
  Even though each end of the cable has a five-pin connector, the cable still only needs four wires.  The fifth pin is an input, and connecting an input to another input with a fifth wire makes no sense; neither end is generating an `ID` signal that could be transmitted.
  [image]

You can probably find other (oddball) USB cable configurations (e.g. male Type A to male Type A), but such cables are for special (or no) purposes (and to be used at your own risk).

Answer (score 0):

Just look it up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Pinouts):

The original "big" USB connectors have four pins, micro and mini connectors (all of them, not only OTG - there really isn't such a thing as an OTG connector) have five pins.

The **cables** always have four wires.

The extra pin *can* be used for OTG detection if the USB OTG controller chip supports that (and wikipedia again describes how: the ID pin is connected to ground in the host plug, while it's open in the device plug) and if you have different cables.

But to my knowledge there are also USB OTG controller chips where you can override this detection and change direction just by software. I do not know if those controllers actually connect to the extra pin.

I guess looking up some concrete datasheets for USB OTG controller chips would clear that up.

Comment: You write "micro and mini connectors (all of them, not only OTG) " <-- well there isn't really such a thing as an OTG connector. Though maybe Micro 2.0 AB could be something one might call that.

Comment: The wikipedia page says "USB 2.0 uses two wires for power (VBUS and GND), and two for differential serial data signals. Mini and micro connectors have their GND connections moved from pin #4 to pin #5, while their pin #4 serves as an ID pin for the On-The-Go host/client identification" <-- well, of the two contradicting claims that I mentioned, that sounds more supportive of the first one (that USB 2.0 doesn't ever have 5 wires), . Rather than the second claim.